# Preserving SCSS variables during rollup build

Tags: reactjs, sass, rollup, rollupjs

I am working on a simple react component library which has atomic components styled using scss. Each component has its own stylesheet which imports a global stylesheet. The global stylesheet has variables defined for colours, gradients, borders etc.

When I do rollup build, the output of this has processed styles attached to each component, i.e. the variables are replaced with actual values and css string is formed.

This library will be used by another project which will decide the values of these variables. I want to give some default values in my component library but allow the project to override these values.

`rollup.config.js`

```
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: "cjs",
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: "esm",
      sourcemap: true,
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true }),
    postcss({
        extensions: ['.scss']
    })
  ]
};
```

Some styles in my `common.scss`

```
$primary-text: #3C3C3C !default;
$secondary-text: #5C5C5C !default;
$tertiary-text: #7C7C7C !default;
```

How can I configure it so that project will be able to override the styles by redeclaring values of these variables? I expect that there will be one `global.scss` in project which will import my `common.scss` from library and then override required variables. Is rollup good option for this kind of use case? Please let me know if any other snippet is required from my current configuration.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution to this problem? I'm trying to do the same myself.

Comment: I am using plain CSS variable as a value of SCSS variable. This allows me to get CSS variable in processed CSS file which I can override due to cascading nature.

Answer (score 0):

```js
postcss({
        extract: true,
        minimize: true,
        use: [
          [
            'sass',
            {
              data: '@import "./common.scss"; '
            }
          ]
        ],
        plugins: []
      })
```

https://github.com/hytromo/rollup-plugin-postcss-retain-sass-data#readme

Comment: Can you please elaborate what this plugin is doing?
From your snippet, it did not create any of expected scss files.